# GoLand IDE would not index files

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

Pressing double shift in GoLand brings up the search menu. When I search for any file I get "no files found" message, even though searched file does exist.

[image]

Comment: Please open an issue on our issue tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go. This will allow you to get the support from our team while it allows us to fix any issues encountered.

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow related to shared indexes plugin. After disabling the plugin I can search normally:
[image]

Comment: I've met this problem twice, I guess it happens when you open a huge file (370KB), thanks for your solution.